# how to creating factors from a huge factor variable of levels 50+ in r programming?

Tags: r

i have a factor variable of 31, counting dates in a month. I need to convert this factors into only 3, i.e 1-10 as "early month", 11-20 as "mid month", 21-31 as "end month".

Comment: Take a look at `?cut.Date`

Comment: For example, see `cut(1:31, breaks = c(0, 10, 20, 31), labels = c("early month", "mid month", "end month"))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `cut` function as Ronak Shah suggested

```
cut(1:31, breaks = c(0, 10, 20, 31), labels = c("early month", "mid month", "end month")

# [1] early month early month early month early month early month early month
# [7] early month early month early month early month mid month   mid month  
# [13] mid month   mid month   mid month   mid month   mid month   mid month  
# [19] mid month   mid month   end month   end month   end month   end month  
# [25] end month   end month   end month   end month   end month   end month  
# [31] end month  
# Levels: early month mid month end month
```